# Connect and read data from Analysis services using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssas, tabular, adomd.net

I am able to successfully connect to analysis services(Tabular) using ADOMD.NET connection and was able to query the data using DAX query in my local system as explained in below link:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/execute-dax-queries-through-ole-db-and-adomd-net/

When i deployed the console app to the Azure app service using Web Job, i am facing the below error:

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException
Message=**A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.**

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: **No such host is known.**

I tried changing my connection string with the below properties also but it did not work:

Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=;Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate

How can i connect and read data from Analysis services using C# when deployed using Web job?